# How can i enable SSL for for Gravitee API Gateway

Tags: api-gateway, gravitee

I was able to configure Gravitee API Gateway, Management and UI successfully and I successfully created sample API's which were tested in postman. Now I need to enable SSL for all the three Gravitee services running on ports Management-UI - 8000, API-gateway - 8092 and  Management - 8093. Can some one help me to configure wild card domain certificate for all of these services?

This is the only official documentation which i see about ssl configuration for gravitee:
https://docs.gravitee.io/am/2.x/am_installguide_configuration.html

Any help is much appreciated, I have certificates in PKCS12/PEM formats.
FYI, DNS mapping is configured for the server.

Answer (score 2):

I eventually figured it out. The solution was to generate a keystore and truststore for my domain certificate and then add the certificate to gravitee.yml configuration file for both gateway and management-api. update the paths in management ui - constant.json file and restart the services.

Hope this helps some one.

Comment: Using this approach, would you have to manually update/replace the certificate every given period of time? And then restart the service?

Comment: yes, new keystore and truststores much be generated when certificate expires or changes. service has to be restarted to take in to effect